# Manually set radiobuttons/checkbox checked as true in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, input, checkbox, radio-button

I am working in MVC and sending  `true/false` in my ViewBag named TestValue to HTML. Now in my html file, I have a radiobutton group, from which I am setting `checked = "@ViewBag.TestValue"` for one of my radiobuttons in that group.

What's happening is, its setting the value of radiobuttons checked parameter correctly in HTML but by default the last radiobutton (in a group) is shown as checked (HTML says `checked="false"` for that).

Has someone tried setting checked parameter of radiobutton/checkboxes using `ViewBag` in MVC?

Same is happening for Checkbox, its defaulting to true even if `Checked="false"` in HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it, As I was passing `true` or `false` as an text value to `ViewBag.TestValue` but HTML dont work on `checked="true"` but works if I just put `checked` as a text in input block. ref (http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)

So instead of passing `true/false`, I pass `checked` or Empty string and thats worked.